# Is it possible to call this operation as Direct sum?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem: Calculate $$((...((2018 \oplus 2017) \oplus2016)\oplus...\oplus2)\oplus 1)$$ if $$ x \oplus y = \frac {3(x+9y)} {xy+81} $$.

I assume that it will be a multiple of 1009, but can't solve it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the direct sum, this is just "abuse" of the notation commonly used for the direct sum. And this is not really abstract algebra either.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it.